# Is it possible to pass a provider from one library to another in NestJS?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Let's assume we have a `Application` and two libraries imported by it: `LoggerLibrary` and `OtherLibrary`.

`LoggerLibrary` exposes a `LoggerLibraryMainModule` with a global flag set that has a `Logger` provider:

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: Logger,
      scope: Scope.TRANSIENT,
    },
  ],
  global: true,
```

The `Application` main module imports the `LoggerLibraryMainModule` as follows:

```
import { LoggerLibraryMainModule } from 'LoggerLibrary';

@Module({
  imports: [
    LoggerLibraryMainModule,
```

With this setup the globally autowired `Logger` can be used anywhere in the `Application` without an issue.

The `Application` main module also imports another library module `OtherLibraryMainModule` as follows:

```
import { LoggerLibraryMainModule } from 'LoggerLibrary';
import { OtherLibraryMainModule } from 'OtherLibrary';

@Module({
  imports: [
    LoggerLibraryMainModule,
    OtherLibraryMainModule,
```

Now comes the question how can we inject the globally provided `Logger` to the `OtherLibrary` so that NestJS service classes there can make use of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we use the @Inject() decorator, This decorator takes a single argument - the token.

so here in the constructor of `OtherLibraryMain` **service** class ( you only need it there )
all you have to do is to inject the logger provider :

```js
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Logger } from '...'

@Injectable
class OtherLibraryService{
 constructor(
    @Inject('Logger') logger: Logger,
    //...
  )
 //...
}
```

[docs link](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers)

Comment: Brilliant answer, works as a charm! Interestingly in the main Application I don't need the @Inject annotation. Defining constructor(private readonly logger: Logger){..} is enough.

Comment: Please format the answer as follows:
`@Inject(Logger) logger: Logger`. We know the types in this case.

Comment: I didn't know its type that's why I make it any

Comment: Any ideas why in the library the @Inject annotation is mandatory while in the main app it can be omitted ?

Comment: @Inject uses a string so its designed to regonize the provider by its name "This decorator takes a single argument - the token."

Comment: `constructor(private readonly logger: Logger){..} ` can do the work too but in docs they recommand this method